# How to Rename the ODBC Data source in Import tables->connect to database in informatica?

Tags: informatica

I want to know how to rename the ODBC data source in informatica.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two approaches.  One, create a new ODBC connection on your PC and use that connection to re-import the source.  Two, edit the source and click on the rename button.  The second field is the database name, and editing that field will cause your source to appear to have been imported using an ODBC connection with whatever name you place in that that field.